# Pagination using LINQ and passing parameter for the search

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The method is working correctly, it is returning all the data, but how would I do to pass the parameters, name and age, to bring this data in the paged search?

If the parameters are null it returns all data, if it does not, return the data of the parameters

```
public Pagination<User> GetPagination(string name, string age, int pageSize, int pageNumber)
{
   var users= this.DbContext.User

    var total = users.Select(x => x.Id).Distinct().ToList().Count;

    var listUsers = users
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Name)
            .Skip(pageSize * (pageNumber - 1))
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList()


     var Pagedlist= new Pagination<User>()
        {
            List = listUsers,
            Count = total
        };

        return Pagedlist;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `.Where(predicate)`?

Answer (score 1):

Build the main filtered `IQueryable<User>` first, use it as the basis for a Count query, then the page of results;

```
var users = this.DbContext.User
    .Where( ... );

var total = users.Count();

var listUsers = users
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Name)
        .Skip(pageSize * (pageNumber - 1))
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jeremy said you need to perform your query in that order to run your sql query on the database side and not bringing the data into memory to perform the pagination. If you have 1 million records you will face some performance issues using your approach.

About the filters that you need to apply to your IQueryable you can do in the same way as Jeremy suggested

```
var users = this.DbContext.User.Where(x => x.Age = age && x.Name = name)
```

or you can construct your predicate on this way

```
private Expression<Func<User, bool>> GetMyPredicate(string name, int age)
{
        Expression<Func<Application, bool>> predicate = x => true;
        Expression<Func<Application, bool>> exp = null;

        predicate = x => x.Name == name;
        exp = x => x.Age = age;

        //Check the And predicate below
        predicate = exp != null ? predicate.And(exp) : predicate;

        return predicate
}
```

Now you do

```
var predicate = GetMyPredicate(name, age);
var users = this.DbContext.User.Where(predicate);
```

If you are wondering how the `And` predicate works, please see the whole code here [PredicateBuilder](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c42694/dynamic-query-in-linq-using-predicate-builder/) and try to include it in your solution. You can get more details about [Dynamically Composing Expression Predicates](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: elegant solution